# Xcode 6 with iOS 8 SDK can't run UI Automation in Instruments

Tags: objective-c, instruments, ui-automation, ios8, xcode6

I'm trying to capture UI Automation script with a sample project. I use Xcode 6 on OS X 10.9.3 and iOS 8 SDK, trying to capture script on iOS 8 simulator, but getting following error:

> Script capture is not available on this device

SDK is still in beta, so maybe that's a common bug there. Did anyone else face this bug? Or maybe there's a workaround available?

When I try to do the same things with Xcode 5 / iOS SDK 7.1 everything goes fine.

[image: That's what Instruments say]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a known issue to apple and that they need to fix this which surely they will...
Check this out... Bug has been filed

http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=6099734162833408

Comment: This is really bad.. Very straightforward and simple base case and it just fails and there's not even a more detailed error message. I just submitted a bug report to Apple too. Hopefully more people submit this bug and get some attention from Apple.

Answer (score 10):

You should enable UI Automation in the device settings: Settings -> Developer -> Enable UI Automation. 
It works for me.

Comment: Thank you! I could not figure out why my script stopped working all of the sudden. What an obnoxious change...